# How to update UNICODE version in TOMCAT8

Tags: java, unicode, tomcat8, webapp2, emoji

I'm using Emojis in a web application, for test I'm using jetty 8.1.8 and work it very well, however I put my webapp in tomcat 8 and not work it, I read about this and find it is because my version of UNICODE is not update, my question is How can I update it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the  pageEncoding UTF-8. I had to use other encoding in my jsp only when I use the emoji, the encoding that work for me is ISO-8859-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can add URI Encoding property to your connector.

In your Tomcat distribution's conf/server.xml file, find the connector definition for your HTTP protocol and add at the end of the connector `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` like so.

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Alternatively you can set encoding via system property `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it but this neither work

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode version does not depend on the Tomcat version, but on the Java version. Do you use the same Java version for both Jetty and Tomcat?

And where in the code and how do you access the Unicode information? Maybe it helps to implement that part using IBM’s icu4j, which can be updated independently of the Java version.

Comment: Yes, I use the same version of Java. I show a piece of code where use the UNICODE, is in a JSP. <span></span>. Already include icu4j in the POM, but I don't know how to change the version of UNICODE. I give you more info, my version of Java, Tomcat and Jetty is 8, I understand that Java 8.0 can to work with UNICODE 6.2, how Can I set it? Thanks for your interest @RolandIllig

Comment: Have you set the `contentType` and `pageEncoding` of the JSP file to UTF-8? But other than that, a simple span tag should work everywhere, since that part is only about copying Unicode code points and not about certain character properties.

Comment: Yes, I set the 'contentType' and 'pageEncoding' to UTF-8, I think the span work very well because when I use jetty 8 I can see the emojis, the problem is when I use less version of jetty or when I build the war for deploy in tomcat 8 not work it.